# How to define a header value from Message in Spring Cloud Stream function?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

Given a Supplier function to produce messages in Spring Cloud Stream function, like:

```
@Bean
Supplier<Flux<Message<PayLoad>>> sendMessage() {
    return () -> getMessageSink().asFlux().log();
}

or this version

@Bean
Supplier<Flux<PayLoad>> sendMessage() {
    return () -> getMessageSink().asFlux().log();
}


and 

class PayLoad {
    public String header1;
    public String header2;
    public String message;
}
```

How would I configure the headers in my application.yml? I am assuming I need some form or spEl function or other.

I've tried using this from tickets filed, but to no avail and the documentation around this seems elusive.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: messages
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: sendMessage;consumeMessage
      configuration:
        sendMessage:
          input-header-mapping-expression:
            header1: spel.function.expression="payload.header1"
            header2: spel.function.expression="payload.header2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish nor are you showing `getMessageSink()` method implementation, but if you want a Supplier to produce a Message in the end, you can just return `Message` from your Suppliers with all the necessary headers.

Comment: It just returns a Sinks.Many as recommended by Project Reactor after they deprecated EmitterProcessor. What I am trying to do, is have it set headers based on properties in the message object through declarative config and not resorting to a MessageBuilder and directly coding that functionality.